# Drag-and-drop file upload plugin for .net?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, javascriptmvc

looking for a drag-and-drop jquery plugin (similar to gmail file upload) that will work with jmvc and .net

i'm found some excellent plugins but none that i can get to work for my situation.

http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can do it with javascript exclusively. I've used a Java plugin in the past and it works fantastic. [RadUpload](http://www.radinks.com/upload/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my comment might in fact be incorrect. Doing a Google search for

> javascript drag and drop upload

resulted in

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-upload